# SQL Server - Connect via SSMS works fine, but ODBC fails

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2016

I have a SQL 2016 Express instance, and I can connect to this fine using sqlsrv_connect() from within PHP. However, when I try to create a ODBC connection it fails. I get the error message "SQL Server does not exist or access denied".

I have verified that the IP address matches that of the machine SQL is installed on via SQL Server Config Manager -> SQL Server Network Config -> TCP/IP -> IP Address tab. I have also completed turned off the Firewall to see if it was causing the issue, which didn't work either. I can connect just fine using SSMS.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does ODBC fail from the same systems where PHP and SSMS are accessing from?

Comment: Well, after I changed the Client Protocol on my ODBC to use SQL Named Pipes instead of TCP/IP it worked.  Go figure.

Comment: You should consider doing a self-answer, since you solved it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after I changed the Client Protocol on my ODBC to use SQL Named Pipes instead of TCP/IP it worked. Go figure